# Containerd port mapping from host to container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, port, containerd, containerdctl

I am new to **containerd** and  trying to run a simple application with Containerd. I am using **ctr** to access images, containers and tasks.

In case of a Docker I used to give command as `docker run -p 8085:8085 imageId:version`

This mapped my host to the container and gave a way for me to ***expose APIS from container to the host and outside world.***

But I am not sure how to do this **using ctr in containerd.** Also kindly let me know if it is possible or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot map from container to outside work using the ctr command. Instead, use nerdctl (https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl) as it has the same docker CLI functionality.